# How to print feature maps with Keras 2.0 running on top of Tensorflow?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I'm new to convolutional networks and have been struggling with this simple task.
I can't even print the regular output of the convolutional layers.

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import backend as K

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

# attempt to print the output of neuron 0 of the last layer
features = model.predict(x)    
out = np.squeeze(features, axis=0)
print(out.shape) # (7,7, 512)
out2 = K.permute_dimensions(out, (2, 0, 1))
print(out2.shape) # (512, 7, 7) -> moved it because I assumed it was 512 outputs of format 7 x 7 (?!?)
plt.imshow(out2[0]) 

# attempt to print the output of the third convolutional layer
get_feature = K.function([model.layers[0].input], [model.layers[3].output])
feat = get_feature([x])[0]
plt.imshow(feat)
```

Could somebody please explain me what I'm getting/doing wrong?